# How do I get a list of all online users in ejabberd/XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

How do I get a list of all users online in XMPP assuming that I'm an admin and XEP-133 does not work and I'm not in their roster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most commands in XEP-133 ***do*** work fine with ejabberd.

You are indeed right about some particular commands not working including getting the online-users: I discovered though there are non-standard alternatives specific to ejabberd:

If you run a `disco#items` on the host you get some interesting items you can query:

```
<iq to="localhost" type="get" id="123">
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' />
</iq>


<iq from="localhost" type="result" to="admin@localhost/jarnas" id="123">
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items">
        <item jid="conference.localhost" />
        <item jid="pubsub.localhost" />
        <item jid="riot.localhost" />
        <item jid="vjud.localhost" />
        <item node="announce" name="Announcements" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="config" name="Configuration" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="user" name="User Management" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="online users" name="Online Users" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="all users" name="All Users" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="outgoing s2s" name="Outgoing s2s Connections" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="running nodes" name="Running Nodes" jid="localhost" />
        <item node="stopped nodes" name="Stopped Nodes" jid="localhost" />
    </query>
</iq>
```

Now in you case you need the "Online Users" so:

```
<iq to="localhost" type="get" id="234">
    <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items' node="online users"/>
</iq>

<iq from="localhost" type="result" to="admin@localhost/jarnas" id="234" >
    <query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items" node="online users" >
        <item name="admin@localhost" jid="admin@localhost/auto-CdB67NUOie" />
        <item name="admin@localhost" jid="admin@localhost/jarnas" />
    </query>
</iq>
```

will work like a charm ;)

Comment: Hm, promise to look into it tomorrow. The ticket is old and I am at least certain you can get the list of registered users, cause I am doing it in a project. Will come back!

Comment: Would really appreciate it! :) Unfortunately my project has to be in PHP :( and it's due Sat. :( (been trying to work on this for over a week now).

Comment: There you go! the non-standard way of doing it with ejabberd ;)

Comment: This works great if the requesting user is an admin. Can I change the permissions for this query request somewhere? Maybe ejabberd.cfg?

Comment: @MarkMolina I don't think so. You shouldn't be able to.

Comment: this is very nice solution but can you convert this xml to ruby code?