# Getting list of all users registered on server with online/offline status using Smack API on android

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Im connecting to an ejabberd XMPP server using Smack API -

```
        username = "admin";
        password = "admin";
        port = "5222";
        serviceName = "davids-macbook-pro.local";
        host = "192.168.20.8";

     config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
                    .setHost(host)
                    .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                    .setServiceName(serviceName)
                    .setPort(Integer.parseInt(port))
                    .build();

            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want to get a list of all online users. How is it possible ?

When I try -

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
Log.i("entry", entries+"");
for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

}
```

Getting a null array for

```
Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
```

Comment: Do you mean all online users registered on the server, or all online users that are added as contacts to the current user's roster?

Comment: I mean all users registered on the server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of all online users in ejabberd/XMPP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610091/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-online-users-in-ejabberd-xmpp)

Comment: I would like to know the libraries used for connection. Could u please comment the dependencies. I was not able to connect to the server it send Smack Exception

Comment: if you are not admin ,you can not get all registered user on server.if you want to get all roster getEntries  first add user to your roster.

Answer (score 1):

```
     for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                 Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();       

                map.put("USER", entry.getName().toString());
                map.put("STATUS", type.toString());
                Log.e("USER", entry.getName().toString());

                usersList.add(map);

        }
```

check STATUS is equals to 'available' then the user is online otherwise user is Offline.

Comment: Im getting null array for Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

Comment: So I cannot iterate using 'for (RosterEntry entry : entries)' because 'entries' is null.

Comment: @Adrian Did you find a solution how to get all users? both online and offline?

Answer (score 0):

User `getPresence` in `Roaster` as below.

```
        Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry rosterEntry : entries){

            System.out.println("xmpp.Roster.presence "+ roster.getPresence(rosterEntry.getUser()).getType());
        }
```